# jquery using autocompete. I'm wanting to add async to remove render-blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi am wanting to speed up the page using async to remove the render-blocking.

What is happening; when I put async in the script before jquery file it the auto complete stops working? 
If I don't use async its then rending blocking.

Any ideas has to how to get both working?

Or

can explain why this may be happening?

It is for a form postcode selection

[site](http://www.vestedutility.com.au/)

```
 <script async    src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script><!----NEED for postcode--->
  <script   >
      //custom select box    

      $("#swSearch").autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, add){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.vestedutility.com.au/WMS/index.php/welcome/sw_search', //Controller where search is performed
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: req,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.response =='true'){
                   add(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I visited the page you have provided and there are a lot of errors on the page :
[image]

1. First remove all async from `<script>` tags.
2. Then put your autocomplete code inside this

   ```
   $(function() {
   //your autocomplete code here
   }
   ```

   This should solve your issue as autocomplete itself is using jquery.
3. Other than that your html document is starting with `<head>`.
4. There is no body tag also.
5. You are downloading bootstrap.min.js 3 times.

Comment: thanks ill clean the those other issues up. Why remove all the async tags? The auto complete works but I'm wanting the page to load faster. On googles "page speed test" the file http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js is an issue

Comment: Here your bootstrap.min.js is dependent on jquery so using asyn will cause issues here

Comment: If you still want to use asyn there then you will have to write control execution order there ........like you will have to check when jquery has loaded and then only execute bootstrap.min.js

Comment: ok, do you know of a way to Remove render-blocking JavaScript: ?? or is it not possible

Comment: There are actually two <body> tags on the page, but none in the right location. Not to mention the two <head>s. Your page looks like a Siamese twin.

Answer (score 0):

Your own code depends on jquery, so async won't work there. Your code would be executed before jquery is even loaded. The developer console always gives you great error stack traces.

On the link you posted it seems like you forgot to include the autocomplete script.

Comment: the autocomplete script is at the end of the page?

Comment: @Wrest "ReferenceError: autocomplete is not defined"

Comment: I can only see the base.js errors at the moment? if you type 60 into the search box it works fine?